# Disable all the events of DOM

Tags: jquery

I am trying to find an easy way to disable all the jQuery event handler of DOM element, like `hover`, `click`, etc. I know I can use the `unbind` to do that. But it will need a of code to do that. I just want to know is there any switch of jQuery to control this? Also, I know there is a solution using global variable to make it. I don't think it is good to write hard code like this.

```
//in some event handler
if (sometag)
{
   //do something.

}
```

It is not elegant for the code. Any idea or something I don't know?

Comment: hi there i found this article for preventing actions:
from: http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/

Comment: hi, friend ,I need time to read and understand it .thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is pretty wide and general. If you could state your precise use case, someone could probably give you a better answer.

Another pattern to activate / deactivate event handlers on a dom node is to delegate event handling to a parent node, and use classes to toggle the handlers on and off.

What is event delegation ? You will find a simple answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8110934/86072).

Here is an example :

```
//HTML code :

<ul id="myList">
    <li>
        <input class="cbActivate" type="checkbox" /> <a href="#" class="link">first item</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input class="cbActivate" type="checkbox" /> <a href="#" class="link">second item</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input class="cbActivate" type="checkbox" /> <a href="#" class="link">third item</a>
    </li>
</ul>

//javascript
$('.cbActivate').on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('li').find('a.link').toggleClass('active');
});
// handling clicks on 'a.active' links is delegated to the parent '#myList' node
$('#myList').on('click', 'a.active', function () {
    alert("I'm an activated item !");
});
```

Here is the corresponding [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e7mHg/)

Comment: Forgive me my bad language skill, I found your solution looks very elegant. thanks. but I have another question here , Does `on` can work on the furture element ? thanks.

Comment: Yes : if you add elements as children of `#myList`, and they match the filter, the handler will be applied.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about just your *own* handlers, and you want to have a global "on/off" switch for them, then having a central variable your handlers test is a perfectly reasonable approach, not bad or inelegant. (I wouldn't actually make it a global variable, just a variable that all of the handlers have access to.)

Alternately, you can namespace your events:

```
$("some selector").bind("click.myevents", handler);
$("some selector").bind("hover.myevents", handler);
// ...
```

...and use the namespace to `unbind` all of them:

```
$("*").unbind(".myevents");
```

...but there's no easy way to turn them back on again, and the overhead for that seems a bit high.

Comment: Yes , Right , It will be hard work to turn them back work again.thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In case you really want to unbind ALL event handlers you can just use `.off()` without any arguments:

```
$('p').off();
```

As an altenative to that you could use namespaced events, which would allow you to unbind all handlers of a namespace:

```
$('p').on('click.ns', handler).on('mouseover.ns', handler2).on('mouseout.otherns', handler3);
$('p').off('.ns'); //only the first two handlers are unbound
```